# rgrep : visiting matches without switching buffer

Tags: grep

I was wondering if there is a way to visit the matches listed in the *grep* buffer without actually switching to the match buffer, similarly to `C-o` with Occur.

Answer (score 8):

By default <kbd>C-o</kbd> does exactly what you want in grep buffers as well as in occur buffers.

You can also simply navigate up and down inside the grep results buffer with <kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>n</kbd> (`previous-error-no-select`, `next-error-no-select`), and the other buffer will be updated each time.

Outside of the grep results buffer, <kbd>M-g</kbd><kbd>M-p</kbd> and <kbd>M-g</kbd><kbd>M-n</kbd> (`previous-error`, `next-error`) will visit the previous/next grep hit without you needing to select the grep buffer at all.

Note that these are all generic `compilation-mode` behaviours, which is why the command names use the term "error", as the functionality was originally written to make it easy to navigate the sources of compiler errors.

Comment: Thanks Phils.

C-o doesn't work the same way as in Occur for me, but n and p do, which is even better.

M-g and M-p come very handy too.

Comment: `C-o` should be bound to `compilation-display-error` in grep-mode buffers. If it isn't, something in your config must be clobbering it, so you should probably find out what that is and fix it.